# Should not I vote to close a quesion in which the sentence " I know it is off-topic' is written?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

There are some question , the sentence " I know it is off-topic' is written at first ,but  without no shown attempt. Sometimes I want to leave a comment to say if you know it is off-topic and you can find the answer with searching in google or some books, Why do you ask this question in BioSE?

sometimes this sentences convince we not to vote to close.
So, I decided to post this question in meta.

- Should this sentence convince me not vote close?
- What should we do with this questions?

Comment: Why wouldn't you vote to close, if the Q is off-topic? Whether the OP is aware of this or not shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Don't close a question if the post contains "*I know it is off topic*". Read it and close it only if **you think** it is off topic. The OP might be wrong in his assessment of his question.